# Android http post not inserting more than two rows in to sql server database?

Tags: android, http-post

Using wcf service I am trying to insert data into sql server from my android application,when I am trying to insert large no of data its showing 404.
Below is the I had written in `doInBackground()`

I am concatenating this string(inputxele) to xelement in wcf service,if I remove some string varaiables it inserting more than 2 rows,if I increase more rows but it again not inserting

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {   
            int totalqty=0;
            double totalgross=0;
            String result="";
            int rno=1;
            String pendingxele="";
            String productsxele="";
            String spname="USP_MA_HelperTest";
            String transtype="SalesOrdersSave";
            String sxele="<Trans>";
            String exele="</Trans>";
            String voucherxele="<VoucherData TransId='"+transid+"' CreatedDate='"+date+"' />";
            String headerxele="<HeaderData Date='"+date+"' TransId='"+transid+"' BranchId='"+branch+"' LocationId='"+location+"' AccountId='"+partyname+"' PriceListId='"+pricelistid+"' BinId='"+bin+"' />";
            for(ProductsData data :_products)
            {
                String product=data.MstId;
                int qty=data.Qty;
                double rt=data.Rate;
                double gross=data.Gross;
                long unit=data.Unit;
                totalqty=totalqty+data.Qty;
                totalgross=totalgross+data.Gross;
                pendingxele=pendingxele+"<PendingData TransId='"+transid+"' RNo='"+rno+"' PendingBranchId='"+branch+"' PendingId='"+pendingid+"' PendingBaseId='"+partyname+"' PendingItemId='"+product+"' PendingValue='"+qty+"' />";
                productsxele=productsxele+"<ProductsData TransId='"+transid+"' RNo='"+rno+"' ProductId='"+product+"' Qty='"+qty+"' Rate='"+rt+"' Gross='"+gross+"' Net='"+gross+"' BinId='"+bin+"' LocationId='"+location+"' UnitId='"+unit+"' />";
                pendingid=String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(pendingid)+1);
                rno=rno+1;
            }
            String summaryxele="<SummaryData TransId='"+transid+"' Qty='"+totalqty+"' QtyInBase='"+totalqty+"' Gross='"+totalgross+"' GrossMinusDisc='"+totalgross+"' AssVal='"+totalgross+"' Net='"+totalgross+"' BillValue='"+totalgross+"' Balance='"+totalgross+"' />"  ;
            String inputxele=sxele+voucherxele+headerxele+pendingxele+productsxele+summaryxele+exele;
            //String url="http://183.82.108.48:53123/GetEmployees.svc/GetAllReportsMethod?";
            String url=urltxt;
            String parameters="spName="+URLEncoder.encode(spname)+"&inputxele="+URLEncoder.encode(inputxele)+"&transType="+URLEncoder.encode(transtype);
            InputStream instream =null;
            String ur=url+parameters;
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get=null;
                try
                {
                    get=new HttpGet(ur);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                HttpResponse response=null;
                try
                {
                    response = httpclient.execute(get);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    result="success";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated please..............

Comment: What is the error in logcat??

Comment: BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));String msg="";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        msg += line;
                    }
                    Log.i("msg=",""+msg);

Comment: Try the above line after response to get the exact reason for error

Comment: This is a security feature. Do not change this feature unless the scope of the change is fully understood. You can configure the IIS server to reject requests whose query string is greater than a specified value. If the request's query string is greater than the configured value, this error is returned. If the allowed length of the query string needs to be increased, modify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Answer (score 0):

> This is a security feature. Do not change this feature unless the
>   scope of the change is fully understood. You can configure the IIS
>   server to reject requests whose query string is greater than a
>   specified value. If the request's query string is greater than the
>   configured value, this error is returned. If the allowed length of the
>   query string needs to be increased, modify the
>   configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Try this:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLim
its.maxAllowedContentLength:1000000
```

or if you only want to set it for your app:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site/<your app>" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:1000000
```

For more information on it, go through [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1066272.aspx?Changing+maxAllowedContentLength).

For more information on IIS server, [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments) might be helpful.

Hope it helps you solve your problem!